# (SQL) In a query, how do I use a CASE statement that would only conditionally require a JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, case

I have a main data table that contains data or a code that denotes an error case when data is missing.  I need to:
1) Display the data if it's valid
or
2) If it's not valid (it's an error code), display a human-readable version of that error code

The human-readable form of the error code comes from another table that I'm joining with to translate the code.

Here's some example data from the main table:

```
Table pub_k12.schools

school_name  | title1 | school_wide_title1 | total_students
-------------+--------+--------------------+---------------
School-A     | M      | M                  | 2300
School-B     | N      | N                  | -2
School-C     | M      | N                  | -1
```

The code translation table looks like this:

```
Table pub_k12.ref_school_field_data

data_code | data_string
----------+-------------
-1       | No Data
-2       | N/A
-9       | Bad Data
M        | No Data
N        | N/A
```

Unfortunately, this data format cannot be changed. This is what I'm given.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT s.school_name, stype.type_string, d1.data_string AS title1, d2.data_string AS school_title1,
CASE
 WHEN s.total_students::int < 0 THEN d3.data_string
 ELSE s.total_students
END "total_students"
FROM pub_k12.schools AS s
JOIN pub_k12.ref_school_type AS stype ON s.school_type = stype.type_code
JOIN pub_k12.ref_school_field_data AS d1 ON s.title1 = d1.data_code
JOIN pub_k12.ref_school_field_data AS d2 ON s.school_wide_title1 = d2.data_code
JOIN pub_k12.ref_school_field_data AS d3 ON s.total_students = d3.data_code;
```

(Ignore the stype for now - it's a similar translate-code-to-readable situation)

So I'm checking that total_students is >0, in which case I'm displaying it outright. Otherwise, I do the JOIN to translate the code. Here's what I get when I run the query (I omitted the type_string field for clarity):

```
school_name  | title1  | school_title1 | total_students
-------------+---------+---------------+---------------
School-B     | N/A     | N/A           | N/A
School-C     | No Data | N/A           | No Data
```

So as you can see, School-A with valid "total_students" data isn't returned. The query works as long as total_students is an error code, but if it's valid data (like for School-A), then the last JOIN on d3 doesn't work because that number (2300 in this case) doesn't match up with any value in the the error code table.

Is there a way to tell it to only do that join if that CASE-WHEN condition is met?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make a join "optional" you would use

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
```

a plain

```
JOIN
```

would filter out unmatched rows from your result

so you might try something similar to

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN pub_k12.ref_school_field_data AS d3 ON s.total_students::int < 0 AND s.total_students = d3.data_code
```